# How to find weak properties that are not IBOUtlets using XCode's find tool?

Tags: ios, regex, xcode

In the project I'm working on, I noticed some cases where properties are marked as `weak` or `assign` when they shouldn't:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSArray *data;
```

I am trying to check if there are other cases where this is happening, thus I'm doing a regular expression search using this pattern:

```
property.+(assign|weak).+\*
```

[image]

The problem is that this will match all the `IBOutlet`s:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem;
```

Is it possible to improve my regular expression to ignore these somehow?

(Of course if you know any other way to do what I want, please share!)

Comment: Maybe you can use `property(?!.*IBOutlet).+(assign|weak).+\*`.

Comment: Nice, this works :) Please take the time to add it as an answer so that I can accept it (and if you want, explain why this works because I don't really get it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your regex works for you, and you just want to avoid matching the same strings you matched containing `IBOutlet` substring, you may just use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!.*IBOutplet)` right after finding `property`:

```
property(?!.*IBOutlet).+(assign|weak).+\*
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TPwPxl/1)

Note that you may add word boundaries, `\b`,  to match whole words only:

```
\bproperty\b(?!.*\bIBOutlet\b).+\b(assign|weak)\b.+\*
```